# get cell value as customize date format from google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to pass the value "input1" to the HTML dialog box. It seems simple enough . . . thank you for any help. 
Code.gs

```
function doGet() {
      var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);//Spreadsheet url
      var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
   var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
  tmp.input1 = ws.getRange("A2").getValues();//cell valve is 01-01-2020
   return tmp.evaluate();

}
```

page.html

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<input  value="<?!= input1;?>" type="text" >
</body>
</html>
```

It works perfect but and get value from cell date format is “Wed Jan 01 2020 12:30:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)” but I want in different format like “01-01-2020”

Answer (score 0):

You could format the date using [Utilities.formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

And if you don't want to hardcode the timezone, you could use

```
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
```

Comment: I tried above method but not getting value as date from google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

- Retrieve you spreadsheet timezone with [getSpreadsheetTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#getspreadsheettimezone)
- Format your date with  [Utilities.formatDate()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatDate(Date,String,String))

Sample:

```
function doGet() {
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(url);//Spreadsheet url
   var timeZone = ss.getSpreadsheetTimeZone();
   var ws = ss.getSheetByName("Options");
   var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("page");
   var value = ws.getRange("A2").getValue();//cell valve is 01-01-2020
   tmp.input1 = Utilities.formatDate(value, timeZone,  "dd/MM/yyyy");
   return tmp.evaluate();
}
```

Comment: following error occurs: Exception: The parameters (String,String,String) don't match the method signature for Utilities.formatDate. (line 31, file "utils")

Comment: Sounds like `value` is a string, not a date object. Is the content of `A2` a valid date? You can try to parse it to a date with `new Date(value);` or format the respective cell from the Sheets UI as a date.